# How to extract the full DLL function names with declaration (reverse engineer)?

Tags: dll, reverse-engineering, dllexport, name-mangling

I have a native windows DLL file that has some function names exported (only the names without any other information like the number of arguments and their types nor the return type).
I need to create a .h file with defenitions to these functions so I can call em later when I load that DLL file in memory.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: That is only possible if Dumpbin.exe /exports shows that the exported functions use C++ name mangling.  Run the undname.exe utility from the Visual Studio Command Prompt to recover the C++ declaration of the function.  Do keep in mind that calling C++ functions without knowing anything about the compiler version and compile options is quite risky.

Comment: @HansPassant This comment should be an answer.